# After using arrow function still this refers to window object?

Tags: javascript

It should have referred to parent as it is not dependent on calling //context and takes lexical scope (I am taking `greeting();` it is taking window).

Below is the example

```js
    var Person = {
      name: "Tim",
      age: 28,
      greeting:()=>{
        console.log("Hello " + this.name + ".  Wow, you are " + this.age + " years old.");
    }
    }
    Person.greeting()
    var greeting = Person.greeting;
    greeting();
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <>
    
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

Comment: Where is your arrow function?

Comment: I don't see an arrow function there.. Did you miss something? Use [edit] option to explain

Comment: I think his "arrow" function is referring to the `greeting: function(){ .. }`

Comment: Arrow functions doesn't contains "this" and "arguments" object by default. If user uses arrow functions then that used "this" object refers to the "this" outside the arrow function's scope.

Comment: Hello I have updated code please check.

Comment: @RK_15 In this case arrow function should have referred to person object instead of window?

Comment: @saurabh joshi - I am talking about outer function’s scope. If arrow function is contained inside another function then that function’s this object will be inherited by arrow function. There are only two scopes in JS, (global scope and local scope) there is nothing called object scope is there in JS.

Comment: @SaurabhJoshi You can refer to following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/q4jo8dne/11/). I have added explanation and example. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) do not have their own `this`.

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target` keywords.

You can [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the object with normal function syntax:

```js
var Person = {
  name: "Tim",
  age: 28,
  greeting:function(){
    console.log("Hello " + this.name + ".  Wow, you are " + this.age + " years old.");
  }
}
Person.greeting()
var greeting = Person.greeting.bind(Person);
greeting();
```

Comment: I created [this](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/q4jo8dne/11/) fiddle with explanation/ example. You can it to answer if its helpful enough

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @SaurabhJoshi, You are most welcome:)